# Shell/awk, get column 1 and 2, run a curl link, assign result to column 3

Tags: shell, awk

I am new to Shell and awk. I have data below:

```
ID Lat Lon
1  20  110
2  30  120
```

I want to get the lat and long to call an API to get the city of that location.
My thought is to get `Lat`, `Lon` to do a `curl http://.....lat&long=LAT,LONG...`, after I get the city, then assign it into the 4th column.

I have tried the code:

```
cat $FILENAME | head -1 | awk '{LAT=$9; LONG=$10} {LINK="$LINK_a$LAT$LINK_b$LONG$LINK_c$APIKEY}'
```

`LINK_a`, `LINK_b`, `LINK_c` and `APIKEY` are some unchanged strings of a link. My code can return me a correct LINK string, but how can I `curl` this link and assign the return city to my file?

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure about your question so based on your statement, could you please try following and let me know then?

```
while read first second
do
   if [[ $first != "ID" ]]
   then
     value=$(your curl command $first $second values.)
     if [[ -n "$value" ]]
     then
         echo "$first $second $value"
     else
         echo "No value for 3rd column here."
     fi
   fi
done < "Input_file"
```

Above will get the variables from every line apart from 1st line of your Input_file and run the `curl` command by having 1st and 2nd fields of current line(since loop will go through all the lines 1 by 1). Also if `curl` command is having some output value which is getting stored into variable named `value` then only it will print 3 columns(you could take them in a output file too as per your requirement too).

In case this is not matching your requirement then kindly do post more sample(s) in your post with more explanation.